# Pass by value and different behavior

Tags: c++

Why does the following code gives a different output when compiling with gcc 4.7.2 and MSVC-11.0?

```
#include <iostream>

class Base
{
public:
    Base()
    {
        std::cout << "Base::Base() \n";
    }

    ~Base()
    {
        std::cout << "Base::~Base() \n";
    }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    Derived()
    {
        std::cout << "Derived::Derived() \n";
    }

    ~Derived()
    {
        std::cout << "Derived::~Derived() \n";
    }
};

void foo(Base) {}

int main()
{
    Derived instance;
    foo(instance);
}
```

**gcc 4.7.2**

> Base::Base()
>
> Derived::Derived()
>
> Base::~Base()
>
> Derived::~Derived()
>
> Base::~Base()

**MSVC-11.0**

> Base::Base()
>
> Derived::Derived()
>
> Base::~Base()
>
> Base::~Base()

Why MSVC-11.0 doesn't print second `Derived::~Derived()`?

https://ideone.com/NF9FQf

Comment: I dont know why gcc behaves like that but you dont have `virtual` destructor.

Comment: I would add `virtual` to the destructors and see if it solves the problem

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth I've asked about the exact behavior of different compilers, not the slicing at all...

Comment: @Zaffy Didn't we need a virtual destructor only when the static type of object is different from dynamic type?

Comment: @Zaffy, Eric: There are no pointers/references here, so one doesn't need virtual destructors...

Comment: The MSVC behaviour makes no sense: there *has* to be a call to `~Derived()`.

Comment: @Zaffy The destructor does not need to be virtual, `instance` is allocated statically, its type is `Derived`, `Derived::~Derived` should be called.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Unless there's some UB being invoked...

Comment: @OliCharlesworth agreed. But do you see any UB in this code?

Comment: `Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 17.00.50727.1 for x86`. Works as intended.

Comment: @juanchopanza: No, AFAICS.  (Unless slicing is UB, but I don't think it is...)

Comment: I can't reproduce the behavior (which is absolutely not standard). What version of MSVC are you using? Are you posting the exact same code you are using?

Comment: @Lol4t0 I've just tried it. v110, v110_xp and 2012 CTP all gives the same output

Comment: @Luc Touraille MSVC-11.0. Yes

Comment: Can you launch your Visual Studio Command Prompt and discover the version of compiler? (just type `cl` there)

Comment: I've voted to reopen this (despite having voted to close earlier), because it seems that the question is not about a misunderstanding about slicing.  However, @NikitaTrophimov, to avoid future confusion, is it possible to obtain the same behaviour with a code snippet that *doesn't* involve slicing?  If not, you may wish to add a clear disclaimer that this question is *not* about slicing!

Comment: @Oli Charlesworth I can't reproduce it without slicing

Comment: @Lol4t0 17.00.51106.1

Comment: `Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.40219.01 for 80x86` also exhibits this behavior

Comment: `Microsoft (R) 32-bit C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 16.00.40219.01 for 80x86` displays the proper behavior here (http://pastebin.com/a8e8zNGm).

Answer (score 1):

I am using MS Visual Studio 11.0.60315.01, cl version 17.0.60315.1.

Using this as `main`

```
int _tmain()
{
    Derived instance;
    foo(instance);

    return 0;
}
```

and putting a breakpoint on the `return 0` line i get this output:

```
Base::Base()
Derived::Derived()
Base::~Base()
Base::~Base()
```

which is the one reported in the question.

Stepping out of `main` and into the crt results in this output:

```
Base::Base()
Derived::Derived()
Base::~Base()
Base::~Base()
Derived::~Derived()
Base::~Base()
```

Adding this to the `Base` class:

```
Base( const Base& b )
{
    std::cout << "Base::Base( const Base& b ) \n";
}
```

results in this output at `return 0;`

```
Base::Base()
Derived::Derived()
Base::Base( const Base& b )
Base::~Base()
```

and this output after all the destructors are executed:

```
Base::Base()
Derived::Derived()
Base::Base( const Base& b )
Base::~Base()
Derived::~Derived()
Base::~Base()
```

Adding a virtual destructor results in no changes (as expected):

```
Base::Base()
Derived::Derived()
Base::Base( const Base& b )
Base::~Base()
Derived::~Derived()
Base::~Base()
```

My guess would be that the output of MSVC is recorded incorrectly by the poster.

EDIT:

The full output (without the copy constructor) contains 3 `Base` destructors. Adding the copy constructor reduces that to 2 `Base` destructors.

The behaviour, without the copy constructor is equivalent to the output of:

```
void foo(Base) {}

int _tmain()
{
    {
        Derived instance;
        Base b(instance);
        foo(b);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that the version with a copy constructor has 2 `Base` destuctors while the one without has 3. TBD

Comment: Note, they are destructor of three different objects http://pastebin.com/CJKiHmw0

Comment: @Lol4t0 It would have indeed been surprising if 3 destructors did not correspond to 3 different objects. I am surprised that simply defining the copy ctor eliminates one of these objects.

Comment: It is at least not clear, why MSVC generates 3rd temporary, it first looks like a bug, and if it is, everything can happen.